# Surviving within SCP-3008 (The Infinite IKEA)?

Tags: internal-consistency, technology, combat

There was an old SCP I liked called SCP-3008 (The Infinity IKEA) here it is: http://www.scp-wiki.net/scp-3008

My question is, if a group of people were trapped within SCP-3008, what would be the optimal way to survive safely?

**For the uninformed, here are the facts:**

- it is an IKEA. The only tools and materials you have access to are those that can be found in an IKEA.
- Every night (from about 10 PM to 8 AM) creatures called the staff attack. You must defend yourself from them.
- The staff are humanoid entities. While superficially resembling humans they possess exaggerated and inconsistent bodily proportions, often described as being too short or too tall. They possess no facial features and in all observed cases wear a yellow shirt and blue trousers consistent with the IKEA employee uniform.
- During the "night" instances of the staff will become violent towards all other lifeforms within SCP-3008. During these bouts of violence they have been heard to vocalize phrases in English that are typically variations of "The store is now closed, please exit the building". Once "day" begins the staff immediately become passive and begin moving throughout SCP-3008 seemingly at random. They are unresponsive to questioning or other verbal cues in this state, though will react violently if attacked.

Comment: Go into kids playground nd close doors behind you?

Comment: I dunno some of the staff are "too short". That might qualify them to enter the playground.

Comment: @Daron IKEA playground have those barn type doors. When you can open/close only half of them. And just close the entire playground.

Comment: I think [this video](https://youtu.be/Vcq1lLCgk7E) could give you some ideas. Sure, the protagonist is implied to be an immortal child of the Scarlet King, but still...

Comment: One important detail from the SCP-3008 page: at night the staff are attracted to corpses of other staff. This includes even very small pieces cut from the corpses. In one case this leads to the gradual breach of an encampment, as the number of staff attacking increases night by night.

Comment: I myself would hope their cafe is well stocked.  I love those meatballs!

Comment: Shouldn't this be closed as too broad? I mean you talking about an infinite IKEA! They probably have self build safe rooms and bunker units and anything else you could think of to keep safe!

Comment: This is just a zombie scenario with extra steps /s

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since the staff seems to be reacting only to presence during night, you can safely close yourself into a wardrobe. Even better, you can take two of them, remove the sliding doors and put them face to face. so that you can stay within.

You can even lay one small wardrobe flat on the ground and use it coffin style, if you fancy it.

Additional passive defensive mean can be

- some shattered mirrors all around the wardrobe (mirrors are available in the appropriate section of the store)
- cut metal springs into pointy objects and lay them on the floor

If you want some attack weapon, you can build something resembling a spear using either the metal side of the wardrobe sliding door, aptly sharpened, or a shower rail where you have stuck something spiky (screws, glass shards, cut springs). You will find a tool box with screwdriver and plier.

Comment: Entering one of the premade bedroom spaces and closing off the entrances with wardrobes etc so the Staff don’t realise you’re in there might also be a viable strategy.

Comment: Spear is great in open area, but is not always the best weapon in closed space, especially inside a wardrobe. Having a dagger near you when you sleep seems a better choice

Comment: @Kepotx, the shower rail can be conveniently changed in length

Comment: Length can be divided by two, but probably not more (at least if we think about the same object), so you've got a sword-like weapon, but it's still clumsy to use in a wardrobe. If it can fold into a smaller handle it can indeed be a versatile weapon

Comment: You can find some _handy_ weapons in the kitchen area, that are short enough to use inside a wardrobe. It's called cutlery for a reason!

Answer (score 20):

Go to the magazine area. There will be tools there, including forklifts to reach the higher shelves. Clear some of these higher shelves during the day, build the furniture you want and bring food from the restaurant. Create ropes made out of bedsheets and the like to be able to climb up and down, and remove the access point when you are up there. Steal all keys from all forklifts in the area to make sure no one else uses them. You can use pieces of IKEA equipment to make railings so you don't fall off and also to ward off employees that try to climb higher.

More materials can be gained from the assembly center where employees combine orders. They have access to rope, large amounts of wrapping plastic, electric tools like drills and basic screwdrivers and such tools available to them.

As time passes, you are likely able to clear neighbouring stacks and push them closer, creating a larger surface area to live in. It's pretty safe, you can build furniture to live there, it can be expanded, throwing large pieces of wood, fire extinguishers and other somewhat heavy objects would deal with any employees that might find you and try to push the stack over, which is going to take a lot of employees.

Comment: This is a really good idea.

Comment: I never checked, are the keys usually stuck in the forklifts? Or would you have to raid some staff room first?

Comment: @findusl I think it depends on the place and what it was used for. Where I go to the IKEA the forklifts have the keys removed when they are stalled away. But during their operation the employees usually leave the keys in so other staff members can drive them away if they need it. But you make a good point: try and find the locked away keys might be useful even though these employees dont seem to be overtly intelligent or coordinated.

Answer (score 6):

Spend the day examining the vicinity (the particular part of the infinite store that you find yourself) to find where the manager of this part of the store spends most of his working time and where the keys are. If this takes a long time take refuge behind some heavy furniture with some knives. When the keys have been located steal them. Use a lift as a safer hideaway. Put a mattress and food in it use the keys to fiddle around to power it down, disable the doors or park it between levels.

Ultimately use the keys to identify some lockable back room offices and use those as a base.

Another potential hideaway would be the warehouse – find a sparsely filled high bay area with an empty stack, find a ladder and build a refuge up there. You should be able find some tools and could assemble a hideaway out of flat-pack furniture tree house style. Pull the ladder up after you and keep a supply of knives and projectiles. falling glass jars, cacti or big heavy tins should deter most staff if they discover you.

(Assuming the infinite store is an endlessly repeating  series of more traditional stores and includes back rooms, lifts and warehouse areas as well as the sales floor area displaying the goods).

Comment: Pardon?... Where the manager lives? Once you enter the store, you're trapped in the store. That's the whole point.

Comment: I assume the manager has an office, or there are certain areas of the store normally off limits to customers for security and such like. That's what I meant - when I said "lives" where the manager hangs out at work

Comment: Of course that's what you meant... in the near vicinity of the store.

Comment: Well I assume his office and the security area and what have you are in the actual store. However I'm at a slight disadvantage in not having actually been into the restricted areas of an Ikea store nor in knowing the intricacies of how a more traditional Ikea would vary from the SCP-3008 variant or exactly what might or might not be included in these types of "stores"? Lifts? Kitchens? cafes? warehouses? carparks?

Comment: @T.J.L. "examining the near vicinity of the store" can mean around you in the store. It doesn't have to mean outside of the store. Or at least that's how I took it.

Comment: @CaptainMan Considering my initial comment has more upvotes than the answer itself, it's clear there are others who interpreted it the same way as I did. The word "vicinity" means "near or surrounding".One cannot examine the vicinity of a building when one is trapped inside that building. By definition, the building's contents do not surround the building - if they did, they wouldn't *be* the building's contents. Then there's "lives", used incorrectly. Instead of being defensive or applying personal definition to the words, the original author could simply revise the answer to make sense.

Comment: @T.J.L. There's really no need for this, *you* could have just as easily submitted an edit once Slary's intentions were clear. A small note though, "lives" does make sense in this context. If you're in a giant cave you may describe an animal as living in a certain tunnel of the cave.

Comment: @CaptainMan The author appears to be maintaining the same position; an edit that changes the original poster's position is one of the edit rejection reasons in the queues. Why would I make an edit that should be rightly rejected?

Comment: @T.J.L. the position in the comments clarifies that they meant *inside* not *outside* the store. Maybe the phrase "in the actual store" threw you off? They are comparing the infinite Ikea to the "actual" Ikea. They're saying that since they assume real Ikeas have a manager's office it's plausible that the infinite one would have some as well and that the "manager monster" may hang out there.

Comment: @CaptainMan If you believe it to be that unambiguous, you do the edit.

Comment: Seems that there has been a lot of interest so I have updated my answer to reflect my original intention and assumptions

Answer (score 0):

Just disguise yourself as the enemy, and they won't bother you! Rafael in [El Crimen Perfecto](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0395125/) lives in the store (as an employee), so if they think you're one of them, you'll be all right.

You can take an IKEA uniform from the closed areas. (look for a changing room)

Comment: It seems pretty clear that the "staff" don't ever need to take their uniforms off.  And perhaps can't.  So there probably aren't any spare uniforms.